# Retrieving data using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sqlite, join

I am stuck with this problem since few evenings. I have `SQLite` database in my application. I have created that SQLite DB from a file. The ERD diagram is shown below:
[image]

And now in my application I create a connection to my database:

```
using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(DB_PATH))
{
    // retrieving statemets...
}
```

I have created classes which represent tables in my DB:

```
public class Kantory
{
        public Kantory()
        {
            this.kursy = new HashSet<Kursy>();
        }

        [SQLite.PrimaryKey, SQLite.AutoIncrement]
        public int id_kantory { get; set; }
        public string nazwa { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Kursy> kursy { get; set; }
}

public class Waluty
{
        public Waluty()
        {
            this.kursy = new HashSet<Kursy>();
        }

        [SQLite.PrimaryKey, SQLite.AutoIncrement]
        public int id_waluty { get; set; }
        public string nazwa { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Kursy> kursy { get; set; }
}

public class Kursy
{
        [SQLite.PrimaryKey, SQLite.AutoIncrement]
        public int id_kursy { get; set; }
        public int id_kantory { get; set; }
        public int id_waluty { get; set; }
        public decimal kurs { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime data { get; set; }
        public int aktualne { get; set; }

        public virtual Kantory kantory { get; set; }
        public virtual Waluty waluty { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, in `kursy` table I have two foreign keys - `id_kantory` and `id_waluty`.

**And now very curious and strange thing happens**. When I try to retrieve some information using normal SQL statemets with `INNER JOIN` statement - it works fine:

```
using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(DB_PATH))
{
    var query = new SQLiteCommand(conn);
    query.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Kursy INNER JOIN Kantory ON Kursy.id_kursy=Kantory.id_kantory WHERE Kantory.id_kantory = 1";
    var result = query.ExecuteQuery<Kursy>();
}
```

This code works fine! **BUT** when I try to use my classes using LINQ like this:

```
using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(DB_PATH))
{
    var result = conn.Table<Kursy>().Where(k => k.kantory.id_kantory == 1).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

**It throws me a NotSupportedException!** The messsage is: **Member access failed to compile expression**

BUT when I use my classes using LINQ **WITHOUT JOINING** another class it works:

```
using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(DB_PATH))
{
        var result = conn.Table<Kursy>().Where(k => k.id_kursy == 1).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

So in the end: my main problem is that **I cannot join more that one table using LINQ query**. Seems that this model in classes is wrong but I really don't know why...

PS. This is *Windows Phone 8.1 Application*, so I cannot use Entity Framework for that.

Comment: Sqlite-net does not support foreign keys

Comment: @ErikEJ, hmm but when I use normal SQL statement as shown above using `SELECT ... FROM ... INNER JOIN...` it works. So it probably uses foreign keys, isn't it?

Comment: It does not translate joins from LINQ to SQL

Comment: Where do you tell the compiler that `Kursy.id_kantory` is the foreign key that supports navigation to the virtual `Kursy.kantory` property? In the entity framework, [this can be done in multiple ways](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583#relationships), such as by convention. How does it work in your code?

Comment: How are you running `ExecuteQuery<T>` on the `SQLiteCommand`? How are you running `Table<T>()` on the `SQLiteConnection`? Those don't work out of the box. What assembly and namespaces are you referencing to gain access to those?

Comment: @XardasLord I have same question as @Shaun. I am not able to use `ExecuteQuery<T>` with my `SQLiteConnection`. Can you share reference link of code you are using? or some more detail about assembly and namespace.

Comment: @Heena, sorry for my late reply. I just had to found this project on my archive projects. I found that I was using some `SQLite.cs` file with that `SQLiteConnection` class which includes `ExecuteQuery<T>` method. This two classes you can download by this link (I put it on my own domain) -> http://pawelkowalewicz.pl/SQLite.zip

Answer (score 13):

Here is code that works. It uses just EntityFramework 6.3.1 without any SQLite specific assemblies.

**I do understand that you want NOT to use the Entity Framework.** To add an answer for that, thought, we need to know what `SQLite` specific assemblies you are using. For instance, are you using [DbLinq](https://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/)?

Specifically, what assemblies contain the following methods?

- `SQLiteCommand.ExecuteQuery<T>()`
- `SQLiteConnection.Table<T>()`

In any case, here is code that works with Entity Framework.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace SQLite
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(@"C:\linqToSqlite.db"))
            {
                SeedEntities(conn);

                // this is the query that DID work for you
                var result1 = conn.Kursy
                    .Where(k => k.id_kursy == 1)
                    .FirstOrDefault();

                Console.WriteLine(
                    string.Format("id_kursy:{0}", result1.id_kursy));

                // this is the query that did NOT work for you
                // it does work here
                var result2 = conn.Kursy
                    .Where(k => k.kantory.id_kantory == 1)
                    .FirstOrDefault();

                Console.WriteLine(
                    string.Format("id_kursy:{0}", result2.id_kantory));
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void SeedEntities(SQLiteConnection conn)
        {
            SeedEntities(conn);
            // make sure two entities exist with the appropriate ids
            if (!conn.Kantory.Any(x => x.id_kantory == 1))
            {
                conn.Kantory
                    .Add(new Kantory() { id_kantory = 1 });
            }

            if (!conn.Kursy.Any(x => x.id_kantory == 1))
            {
                conn.Kursy
                    .Add(new Kursy() { id_kantory = 1 });
            }

            conn.SaveChanges();
        }        
    }

    public class SQLiteConnection : DbContext
    {
        public SQLiteConnection(string connString) : 
            base(connString) {}
        public DbSet<Kantory> Kantory { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Kursy> Kursy { get; set; }
    }

    public class Kantory
    {
        public Kantory()
        {
            this.kursy = new HashSet<Kursy>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int id_kantory { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Kursy> kursy { get; set; }
    }

    public class Kursy
    {
        [Key]
        public int id_kursy { get; set; }
        public int id_kantory { get; set; }
        public virtual Kantory kantory { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'm afraid I used a different technique than you did, because I didn't know the exact assemblies you used. For instance, it wasn't clear which assembly you used for the `Table<T>()` method. So, I used the `DbContext.Kursy` approach instead and the following references:

- `EntityFramework.dll`
- `EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll`
- `System.dll`
- `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll`

In other words, it works simply with EntityFramework 6.1.3 and doesn't require any `SQLite` specific assemblies.

For an answer that's relevant to your needs, what `SQLite` specific references are you referencing?

Comment: Thanks man! In my case i hadn't set my FK properties as virtual and LINQ wasn't populating them. e.g. 

    `public string Colour_Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Colour_Id")]
    public virtual Colour Colour { get; set; }`